# Interfacing to MEMS microphone with PDM output: what is causing this DC bias?

Tags: stm32, mems-microphone

I have a MEMS microphone ([IM72D128V01](https://www.mouser.ca/pdfDocs/Infineon-IM72D128V01-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf), using [this eval kit](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/evaluation-boards/kit_im72d128v01_flex/)) with PDM output connected to a STM32U5 NUCLEO board.

(Background: it's connected to the ADF/Audo Digital Filter peripheral which I have configured to provide a 5th order CIC filter with a 32x decimation factor. ADF clocking is configured to output a 3,072,000Hz data clock to the MEMS sensor)

Every time I start my STM32 program I have to physically power cycle the MEMS IC or else I get a DC bias in the data register - the most significant byte of the 24bits in the data register (which includes the sign bit) is constantly 0x0 meaning the integer sample values are all positive.

As soon as I power cycle the MEMS IC  I immediately start getting a mix of positive and negative integer sample values as I would expect. This persists until I terminate and relaunch in CubeIDE.

Why might this be? Is it common to need to implement switched power to a PDM MEMS IC to address this in a production design, or am I likely doing something wrong?